# Real sleep during fakeAsync

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have some tests that do not work in a `fakeAsync()` context as there must be some timeout somewhere that sleeps on real time, not on fake time. I tried to wrap all initializations in `fakeAsync()` but it complains about periodoc times still in the queue.

I tried using `flush()` but that leaves the timers as well. When I wrap in `async()`, my sleeps scattered in the test are faked so the async stuff is not executed.

What approaches can I use to address this? Is there a way to identify the problematic timers, or to perform a real sleep, or force the queue to empty?

Comment: Are you using `tick` to make time go forward in your test?

Comment: I tried `tick`, `flush`, `fixture.whenStable` and more...

Comment: Addressing the close vote: I'm not looking for an opinion, I am looking for a command or technique that I can use to address the issue.